# How to delete parent entity and set null in child FK column in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is example:

```
@Entity(name="Cat")
public class Cat
{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="FoodId",nullable=true)
    public Food getFood()
    {
       // code
...
}

@Entity(name="Food")
public class Food
{
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="food",cascade=?
   public List<Cat> getCats()
   {
        // other code
...
}
```

I want to delete some food entity, so cat.foodId column set to null value for cats, who had this food.

```
Food fish=new Food()

Cat bazillio=new Cat()
bazillio.food=fish

context.remove(fish)

if (bazilio.food==null) success()
```

Cascade.ALL in my understanding will delete all cats with this food (or not?) So how solve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the relation should be marked as `inverse`. I suppose that would be `Food.getCats()`
Cascade on the Food-to-Cat relation should be None as Cats are independent of the Food entity justified by the `nullable` on `Cat.getFood()`.

Deleting the food would then be as simple as Ryan specified..

1. loading cats where food is set to the specified food
2. setting the cat.food to null
3. saving cat instances and deleting the food instance (can be carried out in any order)

Answer (score 2):

Load all cats whose food is fish, set each cat's food to null, and then delete the food. You'll need to deal with concurrent inserts of new cats with the food you're deleting. They could make the "delete food" transaction fail.

Comment: thanks. But in SQL I do it with constraints, no way to do it in hibernate?

Comment: Right, but this isn't SQL. It's an ORM. You perform actions on objects, and the framework translates that to relational-database-speak. You need to think in objects instead of in SQL. This is the normal way you'd do it in Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

It's the programmer responsibility to maintain that consistency.

From **JPA 2 Spec**:

> Note that it is the application that bears responsibility for
>   maintaining the consistency of runtime relationships—for example, for
>   insuring that the “one” and the “many” sides of a bidirectional
>   relationship are consistent with one another when the application
>   updates the relationship at runtime.